# Block reward calculation in Babylon

Tags: protocol, rewards, babylon

There seems to be a bug in the block reward calculation in Babylon.

For example, in block 664451 there were 26 endorsements. So the reward should be `16 * (0.8 + 0.2 * 26 / 32) = 15.4 XTZ` ([source](https://medium.com/cryptium/preheating-ovens-for-babylon-9ecd1191880f)). But the baker got 14.4 XTZ.

Can someone explain how the reward is actually calculated, and why there is a discrepancy between the expected amount and the actual reward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact formula used in Babylon can be found here:

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/mainnet/src/proto_005_PsBabyM1/lib_protocol/baking.ml#L190

This comes to:

((16 000 000 * (8 + 2 * e / 32)) / 10) / (1 + p)

But note that these are **integer** divisions, hence, in your example:

8 + 2 * 26 / 32 = 8 + 52 / 32 = 8 + **1** = 9

16 000 000 μꜩ * 9 = 144 000 000 μꜩ

144 000 000 μꜩ / 10 = 14 400 000 μꜩ = 14.4 ꜩ

Edit: This feedback is from the Tezos developers TG group. You can view this spreadsheet to better understand the calculation of block rewards:
https://files.fm/u/hb5eazkk

Comment: Correct formula ought to be

Comment: (16 000 000 * (256 + 2 * e)) / (320 * (1 + p))

Comment: Thanks! Could you please add sources/reference to some description and implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in babylon caused by using an integer division in a wrong place and will be fixed in the next proposal.
For now you can use the following formula to calculate the rewards :
The formula is : `((16 000 000 * (8 + floor(2 * e / 32))) / 10) / (1 + p)`
More info : https://twitter.com/iguerDUNE/status/1184095825296871425

Comment: Thanks! Could you please provide sources ? Context ? Implementation etc ?

Comment: This is actually a bug in babylon. there should not be the floor function, but they used an integer division which has caused this behavior.
This will be fixed in the next proposal.

Comment: Yes so it would be great if you could contextualize the answer, and provide more infos, links etc so that everyone can understand

Comment: I provided more info :)

Comment: Hi this is not official info. Would it be possible you refer to official doc or implementation maybe ?